# Left join with two unique conditions in R

Tags: r, merge, left-join, rbind

Apologies if this has been answered before, I had a look but could not find a workable solution in any other thread.
I have two large(>600k rows on 45 columns) datasets, which I have to merge based on two conditions.
The logic is as follows:

tmp0:

```
  id     date    value1
1  001   200001  1
2  001   200002  1.5
3  001   200003  0.75
4  002   200001  1
5  002   200002  1.58
6  002   200003  0.5
```

tmp1:

```
  id     date    value2
1  001   200001  3
2  001   200002  2.5
3  001   200003  0.5
4  002   200001  0.25
5  002   200002  1
6  002   200003  0.85
```

I simply want to merge them on conditions id and date, creating something like.

```
  id     date    value1 value2 
1  001   200001  1       3
2  001   200002  1.5     2.5
3  001   200003  0.75    0.5
4  002   200001  1       0.25
5  002   200002  1.58    1
6  002   200003  0.5     0.85
```

As they are not in perfect order as above, I can not use rbind to simply merge.

I tried

```
tmp2 <- left_join(tmp0, tmp1, by=c("id","date"))
```

but it gives me a 12x4 matrix rather than a 6x4...

Any suggestions, highly appreciated.

Thanks and best,
D.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with code. Just use `dplyr::` before your `left_join`

Comment: forgot to mention. dplyr library is on. still cant make it work.

Comment: Just ran your code using your example data. Works like a charm. Please post the problematic outcome you are getting.

Comment: Please post  output of `dput(tmp0)` and `dput(tmp1)` to your post.

Comment: works now! thanks guys. I ran the entire dataset from scratch again and I do suspect there was a mistake with the class of the dataframes in the first place, which is why he could not find/match both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Likely R reads the first 2 columns of your dataframes as numeric, instead of character. You might inspect the actual type of your variables by typing `sapply(tmp0, class)`.

Maybe you wanna try this:

```
tmp0$id <- as.character(tmp0$id)
tmp1$id <- as.character(tmp1$id)

tmp0$date <- as.character(tmp0$date)
tmp1$date <- as.character(tmp1$date)

tmp2 <- dplyr::full_join(tmp0,tmp1, by=c("A","B"))
```